# Open a submenu on Bootstraps mobile nav when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to open a dropdown item inside a mobile nav when a search button is selected. So the search button opens the mobile nav and now I want to open this dropdown item so that the user can see all of the search filters right away without having to click into it.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown" id="search-btn-js">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="search-cars">Search Cars <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried appending the 'open' class to the search-btn-js element when the button is clicked which doesn't work on this version of Bootstrap and for some reason

```
$('#search-btn-js').trigger('click.bs.dropdown');
```

doesn't work. Would anyone have any ideas on programmatically opening this submenu? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue that the list item, which the 'open' class is toggled on wasn't being targeted while it was not visible. So .addClass wouldn't work if it was called while the #nav was still technically hidden (should have seemed obvious). in order to get around this, all you need is to include this:

```
$('#nav').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#search-btn-js').addClass('open');
    console.log('open that damn menu');
  });
```

So only when the #nav is shown on the button click, apply the class 'open'. Put the above code into your conditional and you should be fine.